# Docker: unable to install Python libraries from dockerfile, though they can be installed manually from within the container's shell

Tags: python, docker

I built a Python machine on Docker (FROM continuumio/anaconda3).
After the machine is built, if I add a further step in the Dockerfile, to install one more library (notably, tulipy) using the command:

```
RUN pip install tulipy
```

, I get an error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for <dependency> which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Without the "RUN pip install tulipy" line, the docker machine starts and I can manually install the library, running the following command at the shell prompt:

```
pip install tulipy
```

I cannot understand this difference in the behaviors of Docker. Can somebody explain?

Notes (added after some initial feed-backs):

- in both cases (running 'whoami' from within /bash/sh and issuing Docker's RUN whoami), the user appears to be the same (root)
- in both cases (running 'which pip' from within /bash/sh and issuing Docker's RUN which pip), the pip executable appears to be the same (/opt/conda/bin/pip)
- Adding the "--no-use-pep517" switch in the dockerfile (RUN pip install --no-use-pep517 tulipy) didn't help

Comment: Maybe the commands are not run in the same shell or with the same user ?

Comment: You might not be using the same `pip` in both situation depending on user, shell, environment... Check the PATH, aliases, environment variables... in both situations and compare to spot the difference

Comment: which image are you using?

Comment: RUN is the syntax of Docker, when ever you want to run command bash or python or any use RUN.

Comment: install `wheel` first and then try to install `tuplipy`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with below command in your Dockerfile

```
RUN pip install --no-use-pep517 tulipy
```

Comment: Tried. But no success. I'll update the question with a note about this attempt. Thanks anyway.